# how to change view with swipe titanium appcelerator

Tags: titanium-mobile, appcelerator, swipeview

hello i have a problem: 
I have two views in a window and I wish with a swipe event is passed from one view to another as if it were a tabgroup.

Can anyone tell me how is it possible ? 
thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [ScrollableView](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollableView) for this.

your code will look like this:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var view1 = Ti.UI.createView({ backgroundColor:'#123' }); 
var view2 = Ti.UI.createView({ backgroundColor:'#246' });
var view3 = Ti.UI.createView({ backgroundColor:'#48b' });

var scrollableView = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
   views:[view1,view2,view3],
   showPagingControl:true
});

win.add(scrollableView);
win.open();
```